Geodesic distance under conformal perturbation
Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold of dimension $d\ge 3$.  Suppose that $g_0$ is another Riemannian metric on $M$ which is conformal to $g$; i.e. $g = e^{2u}g_0$ for some $u\in C^{\infty}(M)$.  Let $d_g$ and $d_{g_0}$ denote the Riemannian/geodesic distance functions on $M$ associated to $g$ and to $g_0$, respectively.
I know that the lengths of any pw smooth curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ are related by
$$
L_g(\gamma) = \int_{t\in [0,1]}\,e^{2u(\gamma(t))}\,\mu_g(dt) L_{g_0}(\gamma).
$$
If, moreover, I assume that $a\le u(x) \le b$ for some constants $a,b\ge 0$ for each $x\in M$ are there "meaningful" bounds on $d_g$ in terms of $d_{g_0}$, $a$, and $b$?

There are obvious Lipschitz bounds. Do you find these meaningful? If not, what does qualify as "meaningful" in your mind?

I would find those meaningful tbh.  Also I am not aware of such bounds.

@ABIM to expand slightly on the previous comment, in the inline inequality you can simply bound $e^{2u(\gamma(t))}$ by $e^{2a}$ and $e^{2b}$, showing that $e^{2a} d_g \le d_{g_0} \le e^{2b} d_g$.

This question is more appropriate for MathStackExchange since it amounts to comparing two integrals and two infimums.
